# Is appearance of PHP file names used in AJAX when viewing source insecure or not?

Tags: php, ajax

All the names of PHPfiles which we use for AJAX functions appear when 'view source' is clicked. Is this ok or insecure? If insecure, what are some ways to correct them?

Answer (score 1):

No, exposing the .php extension in an Ajax call (or in any other URL) is not a security problem in itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine - in fact they have to appear as JS is client-side.

The security risk comes when accessing the script themselves.  So make sure that if you vist the script in question directly (putting the url into your address bar) that it is not vulnerable.

Comment: I just typed the exact same thing. This is the good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

If you let:

- people get data out of your application via HTTP or
- put data into the application via HTTP

then you need to take steps to ensure that only authorised people can do so, and that the data is sanitised appropriately on the server (e.g. escaped before being used in an SQL query).

This applies to:

- URIs that you expect people to submit forms to
- URIs that you expect JavaScript you pass to the browser to submit data to
- Any other URI on your system

A URI, is a URI, and anybody can submit any data to it. There is nothing special about the URIs you use for Ajax. You need to secure them in the same way that you secure the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0):

It's secure, but you can hide the file names with htaccess if you want.

Comment: do u have any links for htaccess help for this problem